# How do I add a loop to this program?

Tags: c++, loops

My homework question asked:

> During the tax season, every Friday, J&J accounting firm privides assistance to people who prepare their own tax returns. Their charges are as follows.
>
> a. If a person has low income (<=25,000) and the consulting time is less than or equal to 30 minutes, there are no charges; otherwise, the service charges are 40% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 30 minutes.
>
> b. For others, if the consulting time is less than or equal to 20 minutes, there are no service charges; otherwise, service charges are 70% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 20 minutes.
>
> (For example, suppose that a person has low income and spent 1 hour and 15 minutes, and the hourly rate is $70.00. Then the billing amount is 70.00 x 0.40 x (45 / 60) = $21.00.)
>
> Write a program that prompts the user to enter the hourly rate, the total consulting time, and whether the person has low income. The program should output the billing amount. The program must contain a function that takes as input the hourly rate, the total consulting time, and a value indicating whether the person has low income. The function should return the billing amount. The program may prompt the user to enter the consulting time in minutes.

And this is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double calculate(char iRate, double cTime, double hRate);

int main()
{
double hRate = 0.0, cTime = 0.0; 
char iRate, l('l'), h('h');

cout << "Please enter the hourly rate: ";
cin >> hRate;
cout << "Please enter total consulting time in minutes: ";
cin >> cTime;
cout << "Is the income rate low or high (l - Low | h - High): ";
cin >> iRate;

cout << calculate(iRate, cTime, hRate) << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

double calculate(char iRate, double cTime, double hRate)
{
    double bAmount = 0.0;
    if (iRate == 'l' && cTime > 30)
        bAmount = (hRate * 40) * ((cTime)- 30)/6000;
    else if (iRate == 'h' && cTime > 20)
        bAmount = (hRate * 70) * ((cTime)- 30)/6000;

    return bAmount;
}
```

I'm not sure how I can add a loop to this so it runs 3 times?

Comment: You should look up what a `for` or `while` loop is

Answer (score 2):

What I would do for code clarity is separate out your logic from your main into another function

```
void gatherInputAndCalculate()
{
    double hRate = 0.0, cTime = 0.0; 
    char iRate, l('l'), h('h');

    cout << "Please enter the hourly rate: ";
    cin >> hRate;
    cout << "Please enter total consulting time in minutes: ";
    cin >> cTime;
    cout << "Is the income rate low or high (l - Low | h - High): ";
    cin >> iRate;

    cout << calculate(iRate, cTime, hRate) << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

and then in your main, loop around it

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        gatherInputAndCalculate();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, that's not to say you couldn't just wrap the entire logic block in the for loop, but it's a good practice to wrap consolidated logic blocks into functions for clarity/debugging purposes. It won't come into play for easy assignments like this, but in the real world, where your code-base is hundreds of thousands of lines long, it really helps, so getting good practices down now will make for an easy transition!

**Disclaimer** I haven't checked your code for correctness in any way, shape or form. I merely took the logic you had in your main function and put it into it's own function. Any bugs preexisting in it will be in the function I've provided. Something like that would be beyond the scope of this question. (Not that I wouldn't point one out if I saw one, but there's another thing that we real-world programmers struggle with: sometimes we're not *allowed* to fix bugs, because we were provided enough funding to fix only a handful of them, and we were told which ones to fix. It can be frustrating when you're the type who likes to make things right, all the time, every time.)

Comment: i understand your code is attempting to be as concise and 'to-the-point' as possible, but so that OP doesn't getting into bad habits; any functions that have the word 'and' in them should probably be split into separate functions

Comment: For some reason I get a 0 for every loop output.

Comment: @DShook well I admit that it may be a bit more than necessary. I did put in there that there's nothing to stop OP from putting his existing logic into a loop and calling it good. Just trying to pass on (my opinion of) best practices. :-)

Comment: @Tom I would debate that. I agree for splitting classes whose behavior has "and" but I don't necessarily agree for functions. Many GUI programs have `createAndShowGUI()` calls. I had considered the idea of making separate functions, but unless we were to create a `struct calculateable { double rate; double time; char highLow; }` it wouldn't be as feasable.

Comment: @ilovenyc can we see what you have, perhaps there was a copy/paste error or something along those lines.

Comment: I suppose he means that user input should be looped to avoid cin/cout duplications.

Comment: @Danil yeah, I'm definitely a supported of separating the UI from the logic when you can. But we would need a way to acquire the input in a manner that is clean. I suppose (being C++, not Java like I'm more used to) it would be feasible to pass in references to the variables, eliminating the need for a struct to carry the data out of the function.

Comment: @Glowcoder: you could pass them in by reference/pointer but this isn't the point, i was merely stating it out so that OP wouldn't get into bad habits